# C# Property Reference

Tags: c#, reference

Given the following code;

```
public class CustomControl {
    private object _dataItem;

    public object DataItem {
        get { return _dataItem; }
        set { _dataItem = value; }
    }

    public void Update(ref string t) {
        t = "test";
    }
}

public class Consume {
    public void Example() {
        CustomControl ctrl = new CustomControl();
        ctrl.DataItem = anyObject.anyProperty;

        string prop = anyObject.anyProperty;
        ctrl.Update(ref prop);
        anyObject.anyProperty = prop;
    }
}
```

How can I change it so that the `DataItem` property is itself a reference, allowing you to pre-emptively set it to point to a variable thus allowing you to call `Update()` without any parameters.

So the Consume class would then look similar to;

```
public class Consume {
    public void Example() {
        CustomControl ctrl = new CustomControl();
        ctrl.DataItem = anyObject.anyProperty;
        ctrl.Update();

        // anyObject.anyProperty has been updated to "test"
    }
}
```

So the assigment of `anyObject.anyProperty` is then handled internally within `CustomControl`

Comment: And you have a compelling need to do this because . . . ?

Comment: You cannot do this like that, as only variables or fields can be passed by reference. You could store `anyObject` in `DataItem`, which - assuming `anyObject.anyPropery` is mutable - would allow you to modify `anyProperty`. I'm not sure whether this is great great in your code actually.

Comment: Well, the idea is to tie a 'CustomControl' to an object via the `DataItem` property. So, for example if the control was a `TextBox`, it could update a prescribed object's value to be the text input of the `TextBox`

Comment: If this is Windows Forms, you should have a look at data binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to store *the act of setting something to a string*, so store an `Action<string>`:

```
public class CustomControl {
    public Action<string> SetData { get; set; }

    public void Update() {
        // TODO nullity check
        SetData("test");
    }
}
```

Then `Consume` would look like:

```
public class Consume {
    public void Example() {
        CustomControl ctrl = new CustomControl();

        // store {the act of setting this property of this object to a string}
        ctrl.SetData = s => anyObject.anyProperty = s;

        ctrl.Update();
    }
}
```

The `Update` call will set `anyObject.anyProperty` to `test`. Note that you are storing specifically the act of setting this property **of the particular `anyObject`**  you refer to in the assignment to `SetData`.

---

To expand on the lambda: we want to create a value of type `Action<string>`, that is, a **thing which takes a `string` and returns no result**. Such a thing is going to be *executable code*. Prior to C# 3, to create a 'value' that was executable code, we would have had to do something like:

```
    ctrl.SetData = delegate(string s) { someObject.SomeProperty = s; };
```

With this syntax it's more obvious that we're creating a *method* - it has a `{ }` delimited body, it has statements in it, and it's clear there is a string parameter that is used by the body.

One thing achieved by lambda expressions in C# 3 is the ability to condense this down; loosely, the whole of

```
// not compilable code
delegate(parameters) { body; }
```

can be replaced with

```
// not compilable code
(parameters) => body;
```

and in the case where there's only one parameter

```
// not compilable code
parameter => body;
```

which is what we have here: the expression assigned to `ctrl.SetData` is a piece of *behaviour* that accepts a string (`s`) and sets `anyObject.anyProperty` to that string. The real power is in the way the C# compiler can work out the types to it know we're creating an `Action<string>`.

Comment: Nail on head! Thanks ever so much. I was basically looking for something similar to Java's Runnable, this ticks all the boxes.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that a lot better now. For ease of consumption could this action be 'analysed' internally to extract the value of `anyObject.anyProperty` thus automatically create a corresponding `Get` method? Or would there be an additional requirement to separately assign this value to a more 'traditional' property

Comment: @Rob2211 At this level we've lost the 'niceness' of properties that C# provides, we're just dealing with 'a method that acts on a string' and the getter would be 'a method that returns a string', without any handy stuff to automatically associate the two. I suspect it would be possible to use Expressions to be able to use a property 'as is', but there's a mighty steep learning curve there.

Answer (score 1):

At first I didn't understand what you're trying to do.  What you're looking for is the Adapter or Facade pattern.  That is, you have an object with a particular interface, but you need to adapt it to a different interface or provide a simpler interface.

One way to implement these patterns is to use composition and delegate the new interface to methods on the existing interface.

```
 public interface IUpdatable<U>
 {
      void Update( U newValue );
 }

 public abstract class CustomControl<T,U> : IUpdatable<U>
     where T : Control
 {
     private T  Control { get; set; }

     protected CustomControl( T control )
     {
          this.Control = control;
     }

     public abstract void Update( U newValue );
 }

 public class TextBoxFacade : CustomControl<TextBox,string>, IUpdatable<string>
 {
     public TextBoxFacade( TextBox textbox ) : base(textbox) { }

     public override void Update( string newValue )
     {
         this.Control.Value = newValue;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I think you're right, this is probably what I'm ultimately looking for. However, (unless I'm missing something) this design pattern doesn't cover the act of modifying data that is external to the class. Sort of the reverse of the Observer pattern?